# Postgres Stored procedure in select statement cannot get the datas

Tags: postgresql, function, return, procedure

I am trying to get the data from the Database use function of select prison();.but i got error .Please advise me.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prison() RETURNS refcursor AS $$
 DECLARE
    ref refcursor;
       BEGIN
          OPEN ref FOR SELECT  round,ben_sc,ben_st FROM prison_issue;

          RETURN ref;
       END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and calling like this

```
     select prison();
```

also i tried.but cannot executed the rows.

```
       BEGIN;

      SELECT prison();
      -- Returns: <unnamed portal 2>

      FETCH ALL IN "<unnamed portal 24>";
      COMMIT;
```

Comment: did not come output...only shows <unnamed portal 24>

Comment: error means data output shows <unnamed portal 24>

Comment: If you want to get data from table you can use "RETURN QUERY"

Comment: boss..give me any example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example code.I have assumed the data types.Replace with the real ones.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prison() RETURNS TABLE(round numeric,ben_sc character varying,ben_st character varying) AS $$

       BEGIN

          RETURN QUERY SELECT  p.round,p.ben_sc,p.ben_st FROM prison_issue p;

       END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: I got error...ERROR:  column reference "round" is ambiguous
LINE 1: SELECT  round,ben_sc,ben_st FROM prison_issue
                ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column.
QUERY:  SELECT  round,ben_sc,ben_st FROM prison_issue
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function prison_issue() line 5 at RETURN QUERY
********** Error **********

Comment: @sarath jay    Updated the answer.

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prison_issue() RETURNS TABLE(round text,ben_sc integer,ben_st integer) AS $$

       BEGIN

          RETURN QUERY SELECT  round,ben_sc,ben_st FROM prison_issue;

       END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

Comment: @sarath jay    Use alias "p.". I have updated the answer

Comment: boss it's working....the output is (r1,1,1)<br/>(r1,1,2)<br/>(r2,1,3)...but cannot come with seperate column why??

Comment: @sarath jay    Use select * from prison(). If it is working accept my answer.

Comment: Now i used select * from prison().It is working fine..thanks lot

Comment: @sarath jay    The * is required.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a PL/pgSQL function for this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prison() 
   RETURNS setof prison_issue 
AS $$
  SELECT * FROM prison_issue;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

You also need to use:

```
select * from prison();
```

to retrieve the data, do **not** use `select prison()` (which only returns a single record, not multiple rows)

You didn't show us your definition of the table `prison_issue` if you don't want to return all columns you need something like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION prison() 
   RETURNS table (round integer, ben_sc text, ben_st text)
AS $$
  SELECT SELECT  round,ben_sc,ben_st FROM prison_issue;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

You will need to adjust the part `table (round integer, ben_sc text, ben_st text)` to match the data type of the columns you select.